# Counting unique values in R and excel

Tags: r, excel

I have a weird problem. I want to count the unique entries in a certain column. Here I have attached my csv file.

I am doing this to get the unique entries in the column:

```
dat<-read.csv("Book1.csv")
names(dat)<-c("user_name")
unique(dat$user_name)
```

The results say I have 170 unique values.

But when i am doing "remove duplicate entries"  in Excel I have 147 unique entries in the column.

Can anyone explain why there is a mismatch of the results, or am I doing something wrong?

visit https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B71VF2HepgVyaFVKSFZrUFhGWm8/edit?usp=sharing for my csv file

Comment: Excel ignores case, perhaps R does not?

Comment: After doing the 'remove duplicate entries' in excel, try saving that sheet to a CSV file, and seeing how it is different to R's data. My money is on upper/lower case significance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My money is safe. Excel is ignoring differences in upper and lower case. You can tell that by converting your data to upper case and noticing you too have 147 unique values:

```
> d=dat$user_name
> length(unique(d))
[1] 170
> dUp=toupper(d)
> length(unique(dUp))
[1] 147
>
```

Note also I think you are losing the first value in your CSV since `read.csv` defaults to thinking the first element is a header.

Comment: thanks a ton @Spacedman. I was like pulling my hairs for the last 1 hour for the solution. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another "proof" of the case sensitive issue using a VBA-Excel routine and your uploaded file.  The Case insensitive -->147 and the Case Sensitive --> 170

```
    Option Explicit
Sub Uniques()
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dict As Dictionary

v = Range("a1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

Set dict = New Dictionary
With dict
    .CompareMode = TextCompare
    For i = 1 To UBound(v)
        If Not .Exists(CStr(v(i, 1))) Then _
            .Add Key:=CStr(v(i, 1)), Item:=v(i, 1)
    Next i
Debug.Print "Case Insensitive Uniques", dict.Count
End With

Set dict = New Dictionary
With dict
    .CompareMode = BinaryCompare
    For i = 1 To UBound(v)
        If Not .Exists(CStr(v(i, 1))) Then _
            .Add Key:=CStr(v(i, 1)), Item:=v(i, 1)
    Next i
    Debug.Print "Case Sensitive Uniques", .Count
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for showing another proof for the above mentioned concept.